# IE closes window and connects directed link in new window

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-automation

I have been looking for a solution or cause of this issue but I couldn't find anything.

My problem is that I am going to a link with vba macro and this link direct me to another link but problem is my first initiated window is closing and directed link opens in new window.

If I just click the link from my email or copy paste to address it opens this new page within same window but I don't know why it opens in new window with vba.

I think work around would be waiting few seconds and looking new ie window and connecting vba to this new ie object. However, I would like to know the reason and if there is a way, stopping thinks behaviour.

I will be posting the code if needed but same code works well with different links which also directs me to another page.

Regards and thanks a lot in advance

Comment: We need a way to reproduce the problem if possible. This will aid in providing more targeted solutions.

Comment: You could check the related code, whether this link contains the click event? When using VBA, if you want to wait time, you could use the Application.Wait(Time) function, More detail information, please refer [this article](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-wait-and-sleep-functions/?). Since, it is not sure whether the issue is relates it, I think it is better for you to share the related code or script to reproduce the problem .

Comment: Hi I am now able to connect new window with searching this new created window but  I don't know a way to reproduce this. How can I check related code if link directs to another page right away?

Comment: About the web page, you could use [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v=vs.85)) to check the html elements and the related javascript code. Besides, can you post the Enough code (contains the vba script) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).